# link to another page not working for when i click on an img but works when i click on a text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

The problem is that when i click on the link (in this case an img) it doesn't link me to the "homepage.html" like I have put in my  . however when I put it on a text such as

`<a href="homepage.html"> text </a>`   instead and click on the 'text' the link works.

I've tried using other pictures, as well as changing the links, and each link (another HTML page) is in the same directory, so there's no need to move up/down a directory.

i have other pages and there seems to be no issue on the linking between pages but they all link through text, this is the only page where I link to other HTML pages through an image. it also doesn't work if I change the `href="homepage.html"` to a `href="#"`.

**after isolating the problem I realised its a JS issue. I'm new to HTML CSS and JS so i would be extremely grateful for your help.**

the error message received comes along as
: "File not found
The file "c:...\undefined" cannot be found. It may have been moved, edited, or deleted.' why would it search into ...\undefined when I linked it to "homepage.html?

this is the relevant HTML code

```
<a href="homepage.html">
    <div class="logo-bar"> 
        
        <img class="logo" src="..."> </img>
            
    </div>
</a>
```

this is the relevant JS code

```
window.onload = () => {
    const transition_el = document.querySelector('.transition');
    const anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');

    setTimeout(() => {  
        transition_el.classList.remove('is-active');
    },400);


    for (let i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
        const anchor = anchors[i];

        anchor.addEventListener('click', e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            let target = e.target.href;
            
            transition_el.classList.add('is-active');
            
            setTimeout(() => {
                window.location.href= target;
            },400);
        });
    }
```

relevant CSS code (for the transition between pages) :

```
.transition-1 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: rgb(24, 24, 24);
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    
}

.transition-1.is-active {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
}
```

Comment: Try adding z-index to anchor tag `a{z-index:9999}`

Comment: The problem is `let target = e.target.href;` In the case of text anchors, the anchor is what is being clicked. In the case of an image, the image is the target, not the anchor. Use `e.currentTarget.href` instead.

Comment: @AlienWithPizza yes! thank you it worked! i realised my mistake ! thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with text inside of an anchor, it works as the anchor is what is being clicked and your handler works.

But with an image inside of the anchor, it is actually the image being clicked, you are handling the event as it bubbles up to the anchor. The event has both a `target` and `currentTarget` properties. The `target` being the originally clicked element, and the `currentTarget` being the element your event handler is attached to, handling the event, which maybe some parent as it bubbles up the tree.

So just use `currentTarget` instead of target and it should work for you in either case.

```
window.onload = () => {
const transition_el = document.querySelector('.transition');
const anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');

setTimeout(() => {  
    transition_el.classList.remove('is-active');
},400);


for (let i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    const anchor = anchors[i];

    anchor.addEventListener('click', e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // currentTarget to get the anchor in the case where the target is an image
        let target = e.currentTarget.href;
        
        transition_el.classList.add('is-active');
        
        setTimeout(() => {
            window.location.href= target;
        },400);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I probed your js code and realized the error is from this line:

```
transition_el.classList.remove('is-active');
```

You should check if the variable containing selected element isn't empty first, then try to remove the class. Try this:

```
if(typeof transition_el != 'undefined'){
  transition_el.classList.remove("is-active");
}
```

Comment: hmm it still doesnt seem to work.. thanks for your help and I believe @alienwithpizza above has had the solution :)

Comment: it might be because it's early, but...probed your js code...hahaha

Comment: did I really write that? maybe because it was late...

Answer (score 0):

```html
<a href="homepage.html">
    <div class="logo-bar"> 
        <img class="logo" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2246476/pexels-photo-2246476.jpeg" width='100px' height="100px"/> 
    </div>
</a>
```